http.post is not a function error - react & laravel
const submitForm = () =>{      
      
     http.post('/createpost',{title:title,description:description}).then(res=>{
       alert(2);
     });   
}


Above is the code inside submit from
Below is the backend coding in Api.php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::post('/createpost',[UserPostController::class, 'create']);


for the above coding i get below eroor when pressing submit button on the page.


cant anyone help ???
